# Custom control binds using .DataSource, but not using DataSourceID

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a custom web control that I have built which is based on the CompositeDataBoundControl class. It's essentially a datagrid type control using boostrap row-col. There is one property called columns which holds the columns. essentially it looks something like this:

```
<cc:TableControl runat="server" id="tblControl">
    <Columns>
        <cc:TableColumn DataFieldName="field1" HeaderText="Field 1" />
        <cc:TableColumn DataFieldName="field2" HeaderText="Field 2" />
    </Columns>
</cc:TableControl>
```

If I do the following in the codebehind it works fine:

```
tblControl.DataSource = ds; // Connect to dataset
tblControl.DataBind();
```

But, if instead I do this:

```
<cc:TableControl runat="server" id="tblControl" DataSourceID="myDS">
    <Columns>
        <cc:TableColumn DataFieldName="field1" HeaderText="Field 1" />
        <cc:TableColumn DataFieldName="field2" HeaderText="Field 2" />
    </Columns>
</cc:TableControl>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="myDS" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Primary %>" 
     SelectCommand="{sql here}"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It not only doesn't work, it doesn't throw an error, I can't run the code using F5, but there's no error thrown or displayed that I can find. It just doesn't run the server. It opens my browser, but I can't see the site. If I compile the code and run it on a server I get "This site can’t be reached - The connection was reset.". It only happens on this page, not on any other pages on the site.

If I had an error message I feel like I could figure this out, but if it's throwing an error somewhere I can't find it.

It's weird because I've made other custom controls based on the CompositeDataBoundControl which work fine with DataSourceID. The only difference that I can see is that in this control I'm not using a ControlBuilder. But the fact that it works perfectly if I databind on the back end but not with DataSourceID just doesn't make sense to me. Any help on where to investigate would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError(); //<-- here put a breakpoint
}
```

this will catch all the errors that are thrown by the application.

You can also try

```
ConnectionString="<%= ConnectionStrings:Primary %>"
```

Comment: I already have an error catcher (that works :) ) in the global.asax that either emails or writes to a log file and it's not catching anything. That's one of the things that's so weird! Also using the = instead of the $ gives a "Keyword not supported" message. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Eduardo, ConnectionStrings is a class or property from web.config?

Comment: Property from web.config. I'm also sure it's not the issue since I can use the same code elsewhere. Actually if I remove my control and use a datagrid with the same SqlDataSource it works fine. So the issue isn't the SqlDataSource, unfortunately - that would make things easier.